# Unstage all deleted files in Git

Tags: git, delete-file, git-add, git-stage

I want to unstage all file deletes. Is there an easy way?

I want to apply this to the file pattern of all deletes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The output of `git status --porcelain` is a great way to build one-liners and scripts for tasks like this:

```
git status --porcelain | awk '$1 == "D" {print $2}' | xargs git reset HEAD
```

Comment: @Jacko: Definitely handy things. You could've easily done this with sed too: `sed -n '/^D /s/^D  //p`.

Comment: My previous comment is missing the closing single quote.

Comment: Old thread but worth noting that the answer breaks down on files surrounded by quotes in git status.

Comment: Warning: this does not work (and fails silently) if you are not in the main folder of the repository (i.e. I tried it in a subfolder and it did not work - as git status --porcelain gives paths relative to the main folder)

Answer (score 3):

In case your path-/filenames returned from `git status` contain
`space` characters, the call to `awk` can be modified to include the
entire (quoted) path/filename including spaces:

```
git status --porcelain|awk '$1 == "D" {print substr($0, index($0,$2))}'|xargs git reset HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else uses git with PowerShell, here is a powershell version of @jefromi's excellent answer:

```
git status --porcelain | where { $_.StartsWith(" D") } | foreach-object { git reset HEAD $_.replace(" D ", "") }
```

Comment: Just a heads up that on my Win10 PowerShell with git 2.35, deleted files listed by "git status --porcelain" start with "D " not " D" so your StartsWith filters everything. Using StartsWith("D ") and replace("D ", "") fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

See the section 'Unstaging a staged file' [in this book](https://web.archive.org/web/20100219200337/http://progit.org/book/ch2-4.html).

Comment: Link goes to a funny place now it seems, but the book is helpful.